# Symfony2 No Errors in Form

Tags: forms, symfony

I am not a newbie in Symfony and I've done a lot of forms in it. This problem first arose when I tried embedded forms. There were no errors that could be rendered in a template but method `$form->getErrorsAsString()` says that there are errors in a form.

After embedded forms didn't work, I tried the most simple example there is.

```
$ustanovaEntity = new Author();
$form = $formFactory->createBuilder('form', new Author())
        ->add('title', 'text')
        ->add('add', 'submit')
        ->getForm();
```

This is the most basic form and it does not show any errors. `$form->getErrors()` return an empty array but still, `$form->getErrorsAsString()` shows that there is an error if I leave title blank.

Also, I checked `form_div_layout.html.twig` in the error block and the `errors` twig variable is blank. There are no errors. Still, `$form->getErrorsAsString()` show errors do exist.

I tried reinstalling symfony, i tried deleting vendor directory and coping the same dir from diffrenet symfony project, i tried even simple examples, i tried... Nothing works.

I am seriously starting to think that something is wrong with my head.

Anyone help?

**EDIT**

I installed a fresh symfony edition and putted all the files from my project to that new symfony insall. Still didn't work.

I also tried the most simple approach...

```
{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

Still not working.

Comment: Consider posting your template.  Are you using form_errors and/or form_row ?

Comment: I tried both. None of them works. 5 minutes ago, I've downloaded a fresh install of symfony 2.4.9 and i'll try simulate that form in it and let now

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get errors from all child forms, you can do:

```
$form->getErrors(true);
```

This will traverse through root and all child forms and get all errors. See [FormInterface::getErrors method](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#method_getErrors)

The reason for this is that your errors aren't on base form, they are on child forms, to get errors of child form you just get it from it's parent and get it's errors:

```
$form->get('title')->getErrors();
```

If you want all errors from child forms to actually be on root form, you need to turn on error bubbling, for example:

```
$form = $formFactory->createBuilder('form', new Author())
    ->add('title', 'text', ['error_bubbling' => true])
    ->add('add', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

Like this, you will get all errors from children that have error bubbling enabled on the root form, as you are trying to do from the start:

```
$form->getErrors();
```

Have in mind that hen using error bubbling, error's won't be available on actual child form where it appeared, so now this will be empty:

```
$form->get('title')->getErrors();
```